# What product can be used to fill 'mis-drilled' foundation anchor holes?

Tags: concrete, masonry, anchor

I drilled 4x 1/2" dia holes 7" deep into my 8" thick foundation to repair a sill plate, but my inexperienced hands misaligned the new sill with the old by +/- 1/4"

I have the holes drilled straight and within the middle 1/3rd of the plate.

Do I get new lumber and attempt to set the anchors first and then locate and drill the holes? (Iffy about that)

Our would I be better off filling my current anchor holes with [insert product name here] and redrilling in other locations?

Comment: Use a good size flat washer.

Comment: Most sill plate bolts are placed with the foundation pour, just wondering why you are drilling new ones?

Comment: @crip659 the old plate is rotten and needs replaced, I lay down the plate and drilled my holes, but realized I'm not flush with the exterior of the existing sill plate, as in the ends don't line up and my new plate is recessed, so I'll have a gap when I install the siding boards

Comment: For a 1/4 inch I would just make bigger holes in the sill plate that just fit.  I would be more worried about anchoring the bolts to the foundation.

Comment: well the holes are drilled 7" deep, and I'm using 12" long 1/2" SS threaded rods with setting epoxy, im worried a second 1/2" hole in the plate will show through the washer and fail inspection ..

Comment: If you flip the plate end for end, are the holes offset enough? (Near as I know, there’s no code prohibition on having extra 1/2” holes in a plate.)

Comment: And if that won't work, use 3-1/2" square washers. (They might even be required, depending.)